# shareactionprovider :How to know which app is sharing the content?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

Hi guys i think the question is self explanatory.The thing is i want to share different contents on different apps.
I am using the below code to share the content which works fine.But the shared content on all apps is same .But i tried searching google a bit and there seems to be no article on how i can share different content on different app?
I don't think the code is necessary but here it is if any one needs it .

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.item_display_menu, menu);
        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ab_solid_reggys));
        mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) menu.findItem(
                R.id.shareButton).getActionProvider();
        Intent intent = getDefaultShareIntent();
        if (intent != null)
            mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(intent);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use two different intents to share different content (and two different user clickable buttons). This is because `mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(intent);` only takes a single `Intent`

Generally this is the correct behavior because you're performing an action like "share text" or "share image", if you need to detect which app you're sharing to, its not generalized anymore.

Comment: yeah i know i need two different intents but how can i know which button was clicked ??i mean if someone was sharing on fb or google,how  can i know that ???Also please help me here if you can ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21065741/restore-activity-after-destruction-activity-lifecycle

Comment: you can't know that from ShareActionProvider, to provider unique content you need separate buttons for fb/google+/twitter.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    public boolean onShareTargetSelected(ShareActionProvider source, Intent intent) {
       shareTarget = intent.getComponent().getPackageName();
      Log.w("myApp", shareTarget);
      return false;

    }
```

this works...

Comment: No it doesn't. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ShareActionProvider.OnShareTargetSelectedListener.html


```Note: Modifying the intent is not permitted and any changes to the latter will be ignored.

Note: You should not handle the intent here. This callback aims to notify the client that a sharing is being performed, so the client can update the UI if necessary.
```